# Cannot focus zero size input in Safari for OS X

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I can't focus on the input if I set it to zero size in Safari 9.1.3 for OS X.

```js
function doFocus() {
  document.querySelector("#input").focus();
}
```

```css
input[type="text"] {
  /* make input zero size */
  border: none;
  width: 0;
  padding: 0;

  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  transition: width .2s;
}
input[type="text"]:focus {
  border-bottom-color: #999;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" placeholder="(placeholder)" />
<button onClick="doFocus()">Focus</button>
```

Reproduced here: https://codepen.io/kevinptt/pen/baoOXB

Answer (score 0):

@kevin Lin I don't have an iphone so i haven't tested it but I think visually hiding input will work for you.

```css
.visuallyhidden { 
  position: absolute; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: 1px; width: 1px; 
  margin: -1px; padding: 0; border: 0; 
}


// add this class when input will get focus

.reset-visuallyhidden {
  position: static;
  overflow: auto;
  clip: none;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: var(--padding, 0);
  border: 0;
}
```

Comment: You can test on Macbook or something with **OS X**.

Comment: The CSS you gave can't work with `transition` since `position` is changed from `absolute` to `static`.

Comment: Try changing position to relative.

Comment: It doesn't work. BTW, it appears that `clip` was replaced by`clip-path`.